# Why does urllib.urlencode append "25" to the result?

Tags: python, percent-encoding

The Python code is:

```
user = "aabc" 
password = "yyy12%"
data = urllib.urlencode({"loginname": user, "nloginpwd": password})
print data
```

The result is: `loginname=aabc&nloginpwd=yyy12%25`

Why was `25` added to the end of the string?

Answer (score 4):

The `%` character has special meaning in a URL; it is used to start an escape sequence. See the [Percent-encoding article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) on Wikipedia. A *literal* `%` then has to be encoded too, and `%25` is the encoded version. From the Wikipedia page:

> Because the percent (`"%"`) character serves as the indicator for percent-encoded octets, it must be percent-encoded as `"%25"` for that octet to be used as data within a URI.

In other words, the `%25` is an encoded `%` character.

Answer (score 3):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_the_percent_character):

> Because the percent ("%") character serves as the indicator for percent-encoded octets, it must be percent-encoded as "%25" for that octet to be used as data within a URI.

Simple example:

```
>>> urllib.parse.quote('%')
'%25'
```